# Joining tables multiple times with ANSI Compliance

Tags: sql, oracle, ansi-sql

I'm converting from Oracle proprietary code to ANSI Standard.

Within one of the older queries within the WHERE clause we had these statements:

**Is this ANSI Compliant?**

```
WHERE ee.person_code = p.person_code
AND eo.exam_code = ee.exam_code
AND ed.exam_code = eo.exam_code
AND ee.board_code = eo.board_code
AND eo.board_occurrence = ee.board_occurrence
AND eo.board_code = ed.board_code
```

I tried the following:

```
FROM people p
INNER JOIN exam_entries ee on ee.person_code = p.person_code
INNER JOIN exam_occurrences eo on ee.exam_code = eo.exam_code
INNER JOIN exam_details ed on ed.exam_code = eo.exam_code
INNER JOIN exam_entries on ee.board_code = eo.board_code
INNER JOIN exam_occurrences on eo.board_occurrence = ee.board_occurrence
INNER JOIN exam_details on eo.board_code = ed.board_code
```

The latter query just keeps running and never produces results. Understandable I guess, I'm trying to join tables and then rejoin them.

How would I fix the above result if the first one is not ANSI Compliant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of join conditions in the `where` clause *is* ANSI-compliant.  Not recommended, but compliant.

The problem with your query is that you are mentioning tables multiple times.  And, some of the tables don't have any join conditions, such as the second `exam_entries`.

Based on your example `where` clause, you have multiple conditions relating tables.  For this, you just want to extend the conditions in the `on` clause, so I think you want:

```
FROM people p INNER JOIN
     exam_entries ee
     on ee.person_code = p.person_code INNER JOIN
     exam_occurrences eo
     on ee.exam_code = eo.exam_code AND
        ee.board_code = eo.board_code AND
        ee.board_occurrence = eo.board_occurrence INNER JOIN
     exam_details ed
     on ed.exam_code = eo.exam_code AND
        ed.board_code = eo.board_code
```

Comment: Oh you beautiful man Gordon! I didn't even know that was possible. Thank you so much.